# LibGDX assigning a specific shader to a ModelInstance

Tags: libgdx, shader

I have recently been learning an implementing my own shaders in libgdx.
So far I did this with a custom shader provider, which chooses between a few shaders based on the userdata value of the object;

```
public class MyShaderProvider extends DefaultShaderProvider {
    public final DefaultShader.Config config;
    final static String logstag = "ME.MyShaderProvider";
    //known shaders
    static public enum shadertypes {
        prettynoise,
        invert,
        standardlibgdx, 
        noise,
        distancefield,
        conceptbeam
    }

    public MyShaderProvider (final DefaultShader.Config config) {
        this.config = (config == null) ? new DefaultShader.Config() : config;
    }

    public MyShaderProvider (final String vertexShader, final String fragmentShader) {
        this(new DefaultShader.Config(vertexShader, fragmentShader));


    }

    public MyShaderProvider (final FileHandle vertexShader, final FileHandle fragmentShader) {
        this(vertexShader.readString(), fragmentShader.readString());
    }

    public MyShaderProvider () {
        this(null);
    }

    public void testListShader(Renderable instance){

        for (Shader shader : shaders) {

            Gdx.app.log(logstag, "shader="+shader.getClass().getName());

            Gdx.app.log(logstag, "can render="+shader.canRender(instance));

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Shader createShader (final Renderable renderable) {

        //pick shader based on renderables userdata?
        shadertypes shaderenum = (shadertypes) renderable.userData;

        if (shaderenum==null){
                return super.createShader(renderable);
        }
        Gdx.app.log(logstag, "shaderenum="+shaderenum.toString());


        switch (shaderenum) {

        case prettynoise:
        {           
            return new PrettyNoiseShader();

        }
        case invert:
        {
              String vert = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/invert.vertex.glsl").readString();
              String frag = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/invert.fragment.glsl").readString();


            return new DefaultShader(renderable, new DefaultShader.Config(vert, frag)); 
        }
        case noise:
        {
            return new NoiseShader();
        }
        case conceptbeam:
        {
            Gdx.app.log(logstag, "creating concept gun beam ");
            return new ConceptBeamShader();
        }
        case distancefield:
        {
            return new DistanceFieldShader();
        }
        default:
            return super.createShader(renderable);

        }
        //return new DefaultShader(renderable, new DefaultShader.Config());

    }
}
```

**This seemed to work.**
I have an object with a noise shader applied, animated fine.
 
I have an object with a inverted textured shader, again looking fine.
 
I have a whole bunch of other objects being rendered with the normal default shader. 
It seems the provider as I have set it up is correctly rendering different objects with different shaders based on userData.

However,I recently found a new object I created with a new shader type (ConceptBeamShader) is only being rendered with the Default shader.

The objects user data is set the same as the others;

```
newlazer.userData = MyShaderProvider.shadertypes.conceptbeam;
```

However, at no point does the conceptbeamshader get created or used.

In fact createShader() doesn't seem to run for it at all...implying that an existing shader in the shaders array is good enough.

Using the testListShader() function above I see "DefaultShader" is in the "shader" list, which canRender anything, and thus it never gets to creating that new shader I want that object to use :-/

I assume the other shaders only got picked before because those objects were created before DefaultShader got added to that internal shader list.

Surely as soon as a DefaultShader is used, it gets stored in that provider list and will "gobble up" any other shaders. The getShader function in the class MyShaderProvider extends is;

```
    public Shader getShader (Renderable renderable) {
    Shader suggestedShader = renderable.shader;
    if (suggestedShader != null && suggestedShader.canRender(renderable)) return suggestedShader;
    for (Shader shader : shaders) {
        if (shader.canRender(renderable)) return shader;
    }
    final Shader shader = createShader(renderable);
    shader.init();
    shaders.add(shader);
    return shader;
}
```

As you can see the shaders are looped over and the first one which returns true for "canRender" is used.

So...umm...**how exactly are you supposed to say "render this ModelInstance with this shader"** ?

None of the tutorials I have read online seemed to cover this - in fact the one on the official site seems to recommend exactly what I am doing so theres clearly something I am missing.

Thanks,

---

*edit*
The place it was instanced was asked for. Not sure how this helps but here;

```
public static MyShaderProvider myshaderprovider = new MyShaderProvider();
```

Its then assigned to the modelbatch at the games setup

```
modelBatch = new ModelBatch(myshaderprovider);
```

As mentioned, my other shaders are working and visible on the objects I assigned the matching userdata too, so I am 99.9% sure the provider is being called and is, at least in some cases, picking the right shader for the right object.
My hunch where its going wrong is as soon as "DefaultShader" gets added to the internal shader list.

Comment: Well, you never instantiate your provider, check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You might also want to consider using the material instead of userData, see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#shaderprovider

Comment: Perhaps I should mention I have read many tutorials including the one on the official site. I have yet to find any that covers this. A lot don't refer to ModelInstances at all, but rather deal purely with sprite based uses.
As mentioned my shader system as set up works for me on many objects. The provider is instantiate and assigned from the main class.
The second link you gave specifies exactly what I am already doing. I have set up a custom shader provider and am using userData to pick what shader to use. I dont see why using a different material field would change the outcome.

Comment: Saying that you've read tutorials doesn't help to clearify the question. Like said, you never instantiate the provider. Perhaps start with a working example (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ShaderTest.java) and modify that to fit your needs. At the very least it will help you create a mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to include in your question.

Comment: I have a working example. My other shaders which I mentioned work. We must be talking at cross purposes here :-/ I have 1 provider. It currently is working to assigning a selection of shaders, as specified above. If it wasnt set up surely none of them would work? my animated noise shader? my inverting shader? without a working provider how would any of those be working :? I am indeed confused, but my question is simple; *how to assign a specific shader to a specific ModelInstance*

Comment: That working example, incidentally,  just uses a BaseShaderProvider, its not even showing a custom one in use. Showing an example of a default provider and one shader doesn't answer a question where someone had multiple working shaders and one specific one not being selected.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. BaseShaderProvider and DefaultShaderProvider rely on the Shader#canRender method to decide which shader to (re)use. DefaultShader is not aware of your userData, but does check the material (and others) to decide whether it canRender. The preferred (and easiest) method is to use a custom material attribute. If you insist on using userData, then you'll have to override the getShader method as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to specify the [Shader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#what-is-a-shader) to use for a [ModelInstance](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Models). One of which is to specify the Shader when calling the render method on the ModelBatch:

```
modelBatch.render(modelInstance, shader);
```

This will hint the ModelBatch to use this shader, which it will almost always do, unless the specified Shader isn't suitable to render. Whether a Shader is suitable (and should be used) to render the ModelInstance is determined by the call to [`Shader#canRender(Renderable)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/Shader.html#canRender-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Renderable-).

Note the difference between the [Renderable](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/Renderable.html) and ModelInstance. This is because a single ModelInstance can consist of multiple parts (nodes), each which might need another Shader. For example when you have car model, then it might consist of the opaque chassis and transparent windows. This will require a different shader for the windows and the chassis.

Therefore specifying a Shader for an entire ModelInstance isn't always very useful. Instead you might need to have more control over which Shader is used for each specific part of the model (each [render call](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#what-are-render-calls)). For this you can implement the [ShaderProvider](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#shaderprovider) interface. Which allows you to use whichever Shader you like for each Renderable. Ofcourse you should make sure that the `Shader#canRender(Renderable)` method of the Shader you use returns `true` for the specified `Renderable`.

It can be useful to extend the `DefaultShaderProvider` so you can fall back on the `DefaultShader` when you don't need a custom shader. In that case you must make sure that there's an unambiguous and consistent distinction between when the default shader should be used and when a custom shader should be used. That is, the DefaultShader#canRender method should not return true when a custom shader should be used and your customshader#canRender method should not return true when the DefaultShader should be used. (on itself this isn't specific to custom or default shader, you always need to know which shader to use)

You are trying to use [`ModelInstance#userData`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/ModelInstance.html#userData) to distinct between a custom and default shader. There are two issues with this:

1. The userData is the same for every Renderable of the ModelInstance. So practically you over complicating your design at no gain. You might as well use `modelBatch.render(modelInstance, shader)`.
2. The DefaultShader is and can't be aware of any user specific data. It simply looks at the information it is aware of (the material, mesh, environment, etc.) and return `true` in `canRender` if it should be used to render based on that info.

To solve the second point, the libGDX 3D API comes with [attributes](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment) (used for both environment and material). By design these allow you to compare a Shader and Renderable with just two numbers, which are bitwise masks of the attributes. Therefore the preferred, easiest and fastest method is to use a custom attribute. This not only let's you unambiguously identify which shader to use, but also let you specify the required information to use the shader (there's a reason you want to use a different shader).

An example of how to do that can be found [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#shaderprovider) and [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ShaderTest.java).

Comment: I have been trying to implement this technique using a custom attribute as you suggest, but my renderables seem to keep rendering with the default shader. Is there something that I need to specify in my custom attribute so make sure its bitmask causes the default shader's canRender method to return false for renderables with that attribute?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. I've slightly modified the test to extend DefaultShaderProvider etc, perhaps that helps: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ShaderTest.java

Comment: Excellent explanation though that clears a lot up, I will indeed switch to Custom-attribute for my shader selection. Hopefully I wont run into the same problems snapfractualpop did because the solution in that link will probably have the same issue the userdata did - "createShader" wont even fire if theres already been a DefaultShader which pass's the canuse condition. The DefaultShaderProvider checks all the previous made shaders before creating a new one.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd think it will probably have an issue, but i can assure you that the DefaultShader won't return `true` in `canRender` when the `Renderable` contains a material attribute that it isn't intended to render: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/DefaultShader.java#L656

Comment: Thats reassuring. Just to confirm though is "materialMask = renderable.material.getMask() " checking the requested renderable has the same material IDs as the renderable first passed to the DefaultShader?  The only place I see that first "materialMask" being set is when the shader is first created. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/DefaultShader.java#L501 so if the first renderable given to the shader on creation has the custom attribute wouldn't it also  accept the same one later? Maybe this is the issue @snapfractalpop is having.

Comment: My custom attribute is working as intended now. In my case, it turns out that it was trying to use my custom shader, but it was falling back to the default shader because of a GL_INVALID_OPERATION error. This was because I was extending DefaultShader, and my uniform float handle was wrong since I was setting the program (a new one) after calling super.init(). I hope this helps somebody.. check the logs for open gl errors! And thanks Xoppa for the great explanations!

Comment: Thats great, seems to work for me too. Good job Xoppa!