# LibGDX Modified DefaultShader not rendering correctly

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl

I've recently delved into GLSL shaders (in LibGDX) and am running into a few issues.

Initially I wrote my own shader, implementing the Shader interface, which partially worked in terms of drawing and did what I wanted with vertex displacement.

I decided to instead just extend the DefaultShader, as I didn't want to change the drawing, and the displacement stuff was pretty small.

**When I try to use this shader with my ModelBatch, however, `#canRender(Renderable r)` is returning false, and when I force it to render it draws everything black.**

The vertex and fragment shaders I'm using are almost identical to the default ones - I just added a few lines for vertex displacement in the vertex shader.  The fragment shader is identical to the default.

**I assumed these shaders are what the ModelBatch defaulted to in rendering my models, but I'm not sure whether it defaults to something different, or if what I added did somehow break it.**

**One thing I was thinking it could be was in the creation of the shader: I couldn't figure out what Renderable to pass in to the DefaultShader constructor - I tried to find calls to this somewhere in the source but didn't have any luck.**

Here is the actual rendering call (this draws right if I don't pass in shader to the render call, but obviously doesn't give me the functionality I want):

```
if(assets.getPlayerInstance() != null){

        if(shader == null){
            shader = new WarpShader(assets.getPlayerInstance().getRenderable(new Renderable()));
            shader.init();
        }

        shader.updatePlayerPosition(assets.getPlayerInstance().transform.getTranslation(vec3Buff));

        modelBatch.begin(cam);

        modelBatch.render(assets.getInstances(), environment, shader);

        modelBatch.render(assets.getPlayerInstance(), environment);

        modelBatch.end();

    }
```

Here is my shader class, as you can see it does pretty much nothing extra:

```
public class WarpShader extends DefaultShader {

private Vector3 playerPosition = new Vector3();

public WarpShader(Renderable renderable) {
    super(renderable, new Config(Gdx.files.internal("data/shaders/test.vertex.glsl").readString()
            , Gdx.files.internal("data/shaders/test.frag.glsl").readString()));
}

@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Shader other) {
    return super.compareTo(other);
}

@Override
public boolean canRender(Renderable instance) {

    return super.canRender(instance);
}

@Override
public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext context) {   
    super.begin(camera, context);
}

@Override
public void render(Renderable renderable) {
    program.setUniform3fv("u_playerPos", new float[]{playerPosition.x,  playerPosition.y,  playerPosition.z}, 0, 3);
    super.render(renderable);
}

public void updatePlayerPosition(Vector3 pos){
    playerPosition=pos;
}

@Override
public void end() {
    super.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}
```

}

And here is my vertex shader (probably don't need to read this, really didn't add much):

```
#if defined(diffuseTextureFlag) || defined(specularTextureFlag)
#define textureFlag
#endif

#if defined(specularTextureFlag) || defined(specularColorFlag)
#define specularFlag
#endif

#if defined(specularFlag) || defined(fogFlag)
#define cameraPositionFlag
#endif

attribute vec3 a_position;
uniform mat4 u_projViewTrans;

uniform vec3 u_playerPos;  // ADDED THIS

#if defined(colorFlag)
varying vec4 v_color;
attribute vec4 a_color;
#endif // colorFlag

#ifdef normalFlag
attribute vec3 a_normal;
uniform mat3 u_normalMatrix;
varying vec3 v_normal;
#endif // normalFlag

#ifdef textureFlag
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
#endif // textureFlag

#ifdef diffuseTextureFlag
uniform vec4 u_diffuseUVTransform;
varying vec2 v_diffuseUV;
#endif

#ifdef specularTextureFlag
uniform vec4 u_specularUVTransform;
varying vec2 v_specularUV;
#endif

#ifdef boneWeight0Flag
#define boneWeightsFlag
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight0;
#endif //boneWeight0Flag

#ifdef boneWeight1Flag
#ifndef boneWeightsFlag
#define boneWeightsFlag
#endif
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight1;
#endif //boneWeight1Flag

#ifdef boneWeight2Flag
#ifndef boneWeightsFlag
#define boneWeightsFlag
#endif
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight2;
#endif //boneWeight2Flag

#ifdef boneWeight3Flag
#ifndef boneWeightsFlag
#define boneWeightsFlag
#endif
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight3;
#endif //boneWeight3Flag

#ifdef boneWeight4Flag
#ifndef boneWeightsFlag
#define boneWeightsFlag
#endif
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight4;
#endif //boneWeight4Flag

#ifdef boneWeight5Flag
#ifndef boneWeightsFlag
#define boneWeightsFlag
#endif
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight5;
#endif //boneWeight5Flag

#ifdef boneWeight6Flag
#ifndef boneWeightsFlag
#define boneWeightsFlag
#endif
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight6;
#endif //boneWeight6Flag

#ifdef boneWeight7Flag
#ifndef boneWeightsFlag
#define boneWeightsFlag
#endif
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight7;
#endif //boneWeight7Flag

#if defined(numBones) && defined(boneWeightsFlag)
#if (numBones > 0) 
#define skinningFlag
#endif
#endif

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;

#if defined(numBones)
#if numBones > 0
uniform mat4 u_bones[numBones];
#endif //numBones
#endif

#ifdef shininessFlag
uniform float u_shininess;
#else
const float u_shininess = 20.0;
#endif // shininessFlag

#ifdef blendedFlag
uniform float u_opacity;
varying float v_opacity;

#ifdef alphaTestFlag
uniform float u_alphaTest;
varying float v_alphaTest;
#endif //alphaTestFlag
#endif // blendedFlag

#ifdef lightingFlag
varying vec3 v_lightDiffuse;

#ifdef ambientLightFlag
uniform vec3 u_ambientLight;
#endif // ambientLightFlag

#ifdef ambientCubemapFlag
uniform vec3 u_ambientCubemap[6];
#endif // ambientCubemapFlag 

#ifdef sphericalHarmonicsFlag
uniform vec3 u_sphericalHarmonics[9];
#endif //sphericalHarmonicsFlag

#ifdef specularFlag
varying vec3 v_lightSpecular;
#endif // specularFlag

#ifdef cameraPositionFlag
uniform vec4 u_cameraPosition;
#endif // cameraPositionFlag

#ifdef fogFlag
varying float v_fog;
#endif // fogFlag


#if defined(numDirectionalLights) && (numDirectionalLights > 0)
struct DirectionalLight
{
    vec3 color;
    vec3 direction;
};
uniform DirectionalLight u_dirLights[numDirectionalLights];
#endif // numDirectionalLights

#if defined(numPointLights) && (numPointLights > 0)
struct PointLight
{
    vec3 color;
    vec3 position;
};
uniform PointLight u_pointLights[numPointLights];
#endif // numPointLights

#if defined(ambientLightFlag) || defined(ambientCubemapFlag) || defined(sphericalHarmonicsFlag)
#define ambientFlag
#endif //ambientFlag

#ifdef shadowMapFlag
uniform mat4 u_shadowMapProjViewTrans;
varying vec3 v_shadowMapUv;
#define separateAmbientFlag
#endif //shadowMapFlag

#if defined(ambientFlag) && defined(separateAmbientFlag)
varying vec3 v_ambientLight;
#endif //separateAmbientFlag

#endif // lightingFlag

void main() {
    #ifdef diffuseTextureFlag
        v_diffuseUV = u_diffuseUVTransform.xy + a_texCoord0 * u_diffuseUVTransform.zw;
    #endif //diffuseTextureFlag

    #ifdef specularTextureFlag
        v_specularUV = u_specularUVTransform.xy + a_texCoord0 * u_specularUVTransform.zw;
    #endif //specularTextureFlag

    #if defined(colorFlag)
        v_color = a_color;
    #endif // colorFlag

    #ifdef blendedFlag
        v_opacity = u_opacity;
        #ifdef alphaTestFlag
            v_alphaTest = u_alphaTest;
        #endif //alphaTestFlag
    #endif // blendedFlag

    #ifdef skinningFlag
        mat4 skinning = mat4(0.0);
        #ifdef boneWeight0Flag
            skinning += (a_boneWeight0.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight0.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight0Flag
        #ifdef boneWeight1Flag              
            skinning += (a_boneWeight1.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight1.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight1Flag
        #ifdef boneWeight2Flag      
            skinning += (a_boneWeight2.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight2.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight2Flag
        #ifdef boneWeight3Flag
            skinning += (a_boneWeight3.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight3.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight3Flag
        #ifdef boneWeight4Flag
            skinning += (a_boneWeight4.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight4.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight4Flag
        #ifdef boneWeight5Flag
            skinning += (a_boneWeight5.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight5.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight5Flag
        #ifdef boneWeight6Flag
            skinning += (a_boneWeight6.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight6.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight6Flag
        #ifdef boneWeight7Flag
            skinning += (a_boneWeight7.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight7.x)];
        #endif //boneWeight7Flag
    #endif //skinningFlag

    #ifdef skinningFlag
        vec4 pos = u_worldTrans * skinning * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
        vec4 playerPos = u_worldTrans * skinning * vec4(u_playerPos, 1.0); // ADDED THIS
    #else
        vec4 pos = u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
        vec4 playerPos = u_worldTrans * vec4(u_playerPos, 1.0); // ADDED THIS
    #endif

    gl_Position = u_projViewTrans * pos;

    //Apply horizon                             // ADDED THESE 3 LINES
    vec4 playerWorld = u_projViewTrans * playerPos;
    float xDelta = (gl_Position[1] - playerWorld[0]);
    gl_Position[1] += xDelta*xDelta*-0.002;

    #ifdef shadowMapFlag
        vec4 spos = u_shadowMapProjViewTrans * pos;
        v_shadowMapUv.xy = (spos.xy / spos.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;
        v_shadowMapUv.z = min(spos.z * 0.5 + 0.5, 0.998);
    #endif //shadowMapFlag

    #if defined(normalFlag)
        #if defined(skinningFlag)
            vec3 normal = normalize((u_worldTrans * skinning * vec4(a_normal, 0.0)).xyz);
        #else
            vec3 normal = normalize(u_normalMatrix * a_normal);
        #endif
        v_normal = normal;
    #endif // normalFlag

    #ifdef fogFlag
        vec3 flen = u_cameraPosition.xyz - pos.xyz;
        float fog = dot(flen, flen) * u_cameraPosition.w;
        v_fog = min(fog, 1.0);
    #endif

    #ifdef lightingFlag
        #if defined(ambientLightFlag)
            vec3 ambientLight = u_ambientLight;
        #elif defined(ambientFlag)
            vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.0);
        #endif

        #ifdef ambientCubemapFlag       
            vec3 squaredNormal = normal * normal;
            vec3 isPositive  = step(0.0, normal);
            ambientLight += squaredNormal.x * mix(u_ambientCubemap[0], u_ambientCubemap[1], isPositive.x) +
                    squaredNormal.y * mix(u_ambientCubemap[2], u_ambientCubemap[3], isPositive.y) +
                    squaredNormal.z * mix(u_ambientCubemap[4], u_ambientCubemap[5], isPositive.z);
        #endif // ambientCubemapFlag

        #ifdef sphericalHarmonicsFlag
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[0];
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[1] * normal.x;
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[2] * normal.y;
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[3] * normal.z;
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[4] * (normal.x * normal.z);
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[5] * (normal.z * normal.y);
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[6] * (normal.y * normal.x);
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[7] * (3.0 * normal.z * normal.z - 1.0);
            ambientLight += u_sphericalHarmonics[8] * (normal.x * normal.x - normal.y * normal.y);          
        #endif // sphericalHarmonicsFlag

        #ifdef ambientFlag
            #ifdef separateAmbientFlag
                v_ambientLight = ambientLight;
                v_lightDiffuse = vec3(0.0);
            #else
                v_lightDiffuse = ambientLight;
            #endif //separateAmbientFlag
        #else
            v_lightDiffuse = vec3(0.0);
        #endif //ambientFlag


        #ifdef specularFlag
            v_lightSpecular = vec3(0.0);
            vec3 viewVec = normalize(u_cameraPosition.xyz - pos.xyz);
        #endif // specularFlag

        #if defined(numDirectionalLights) && (numDirectionalLights > 0) && defined(normalFlag)
            for (int i = 0; i < numDirectionalLights; i++) {
                vec3 lightDir = -u_dirLights[i].direction;
                float NdotL = clamp(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0, 1.0);
                vec3 value = u_dirLights[i].color * NdotL;
                v_lightDiffuse += value;
                #ifdef specularFlag
                    float halfDotView = max(0.0, dot(normal, normalize(lightDir + viewVec)));
                    v_lightSpecular += value * pow(halfDotView, u_shininess);
                #endif // specularFlag
            }
        #endif // numDirectionalLights

        #if defined(numPointLights) && (numPointLights > 0) && defined(normalFlag)
            for (int i = 0; i < numPointLights; i++) {
                vec3 lightDir = u_pointLights[i].position - pos.xyz;
                float dist2 = dot(lightDir, lightDir);
                lightDir *= inversesqrt(dist2);
                float NdotL = clamp(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0, 1.0);
                vec3 value = u_pointLights[i].color * (NdotL / (1.0 + dist2));
                v_lightDiffuse += value;
                #ifdef specularFlag
                    float halfDotView = max(0.0, dot(normal, normalize(lightDir + viewVec)));
                    v_lightSpecular += value * pow(halfDotView, u_shininess);
                #endif // specularFlag
            }
        #endif // numPointLights
    #endif // lightingFlag
}
```

The fragment shader is just this one:

[LibGDX Default Fragment Shader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.fragment.glsl)

Thanks!

Comment: wow that is a lot of `#ifdef` ...  do you actually have the defines for them ? all I see is conditional defines but the condition defines are nowhere ... my bet is that your attempt is missing defines for the GLSL compiler. If you use default shader in some framework is high likely that framework is adding those defines itself but when you modify and use the shader yourself you do not have them ... but I am not familiar with libgfx so I may be wrong. Also the title is bit misleading for me **Default shader** invokes in me the **fixed function** which is something completely else.

Comment: Call `System.out.println(shader.program.getLog());` and it will tell you why the shader's not compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DefaultShader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#default-shader) is a so called uber shader. You can't simply create one instance of it and use it for all rendering. Instead it needs to be compiled for a specific use-case. This is what the Renderable constructor argument is used for.

Instead of specifying the shader in the draw call you should instead provide your own [ShaderProvider](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#shaderprovider). Luckily this is very simple with just a few lines of code:

```
modelBatch = new ModelBatch(new DefaultShaderProvider() {
    @Override
    protected Shader createShader (Renderable renderable) {
        return new WarpShader(renderable);
    }
});
```

Make sure to read [this wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch), it provides more in depth information as well as how to customize it further, e.g. when you want to fall back to the default shader.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553409/libgdx-how-to-use-shader-in-3d/22620390#22620390) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590802/libgdx-assigning-a-specific-shader-to-a-modelinstance/28647473#28647473).

Comment: Thanks so much!  That makes sense now.  By the way, I'm finding your tutorials very helpful with all this shader stuff.  I find it hard to get my head around!